# How to prevent user from navigating away from current view in Siebel

Tags: javascript, crm, siebel

Prevent user from navigating away from current view in Siebel(e.g. Service tab to Activity/Contact/Opportunity) until SR has been transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a RunTime event for Application "ViewDeactivated". Give the view name in ObjectName.You could Invoke a DataValidationManager rule set from there and throw an error if user should NOT navigate out of the view.

If this does not work, you will need to write eScript at Application level. On the Application_PreNavigate event, check for Application().ActiveViewName() and do the validation here and RaiseErrorText. Or invoke the DVM from here. The PreNavigate event should work because it is triggered before the View is unloaded.